# How can i wait for initializecomponent to be done

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm building an XAML app for Win 8 metro and ran into a "problem".

I have my mainpage.xaml with a button and in the mainpage.xaml.cs i have my constructor with initializecomponent(). when i click the button i call this function method:

```
private void GoToOtherPage()
{ 
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MySecondPage));
}
```

and works just fine.
However, in the contructor i also have a condition, and if true just carry on, but if it's false i want to run the GoToOtherPage() as well.
the constructor then looks somtehing like this

```
Public Mainpage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(....)
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
    else
    {
        GoToOtherPage();
    }
}
```

Since the initializecomponent() not is ready when this happens, i get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` which i (think) have found is refferring to this.Frame.

How should i do this the correct way? Put something like "WaitForThisFormToBeReady()" before the .Navigate or am i just on the complete wrong track here?

Answer (score 0):

I think `this.Frame` becomes non-null after the page has been navigated to, so you could override `OnNavigatedTo` to handle it. Otherwise you can grab the `Frame` through `(Frame)Window.Current.Content`, a property on your `App` class or a `NavigationService` implementation - depending on how far you went with design patternizing your app.

Comment: i tried the override and it gave me no errors and it runs the code but is does not switch page. i also tried the this.content= new otherpage(); whick works but then the Frame.GoBack() in otherpage crashes. :)

Comment: I think you can't navigate inside of another navigate call... :) You might need to run it using `Dispatcher.RunAsync()` to delay it a bit.